# What is causing the React not a function error?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass a state from a child to a parent using class based components. Why do I keep getting the this.props.onSortSelect is not a function? I have tried decoding similar questions but can't come to a fix. Thanks in advance.

Child:

```
class Sort extends React.Component {
  state = { descending: true };

  onSortSelect = () => {

    if(this.state.descending) {
      this.setState({ descending: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ descending: true });
    }

    this.props.onSortSelect(this.state.descending);
  }

  render() {

    const buttonText = this.state.descending ? 'Sort Descending' : 'Sort Ascending';

    return(
      <div class="sort">
        <a onClick={this.onSortSelect}>{buttonText}</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Parent:

```
class FiltersAndSort extends React.Component {

  onSortSelect = (sort) => {
    console.log(sort);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div class="filters-and-sort">
        <Filter />
        <Sort />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the function down

```
<Sort />
```

should become

```
<Sort onSortSelect={ this.onSortSelect } />
```

---

But you will also have to fix the `onSortSelect` of the `Sort` component.

As the `this.state.descending` you are passing to the method is not the updated one.

```js
onSortSelect = () => {

  this.setState((currentState) => ({
      descending: !currentState.descending
    }), () => {
      this.props.onSortSelect(this.state.descending);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @BoJack added one more fix you will likely need, if you want the parent component to receive the updated `descending` value.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to understand the extra code. What do you mean by currentState? Is it a keyword? Sorry I'm just learning React!

Comment: @BoJack if this answer solved your problem, you should [mark it as the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Am I right in saying that the onSortSelect code is changing the state of descending (true to false or false to true) and then running a callback to pass this state to the parent?

Comment: Just want to clarify I now understand that I would have to change the onSortSelect code to what you sent because of the asynchronous nature of setState()

Comment: @Bojack see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate for the syntax. `setState` is async, so you cannot expect the `this.state.descending` to be updated right after calling `setState`. But the `setState` function accepts a second parameter, a callback, that is called right after the state has been really updated. Then you can access the `this.state`. The syntax with the `currentState` is to avoid missing some of the click because the state is not yet updated. `currentState` is just the name i used.